# Grunt keeps erroring with "module path does not exist"

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, requirejs

I'm trying to run grunt on a new machine and it won't compile.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task { [Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: /Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/../../../bower_components/almond/almond.js for module named: ../../../bower_components/almond/almond. Path is relative to: /Volumes/Users/dtdtdg
    at /Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-requirejs/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:26824:35 ]   originalError: [Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: /Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/../../../bower_components/almond/almond.js for module named: ../../../bower_components/almond/almond. Path is relative to: /Volumes/Users/dtdtdg] }
```

I've run `sudo npm install -g bower-installer` and `sudo npm install -g bower` just to ensure I'm not missing any packages on this machine. Still no luck.

My grunt file is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'copy',
        'sass',
        'requirejs'
    ]);

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        copy: {
            main: {
                cwd: 'bower_components/foundation/css/',
                src: '*',
                dest: 'assets/css/vendor/foundation/',
                expand: true,
                rename: function(dest, src) {
                    return (dest + src).replace('.css', '.scss');
                }
            }
        },

        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: 'assets/js/src',
                    include: ['require-main'],
                    mainConfigFile: 'assets/js/src/require-main.js',
                    name: '../../../bower_components/almond/almond',
                    out: 'assets/js/build/app.js'
                }
            }
        },

        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'assets/css/build/styles.css': 'assets/css/src/manifest.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['assets/css/src/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
            //scripts:{
                //files:['assets/js/src/**/*.js'],
                //tasks:['requirejs']
            //}
        }

    });

};
```

Ok I've now fixed this by running `bower install almond` but now have the following error:

```
Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/routers/router.js'
In module tree:
    require-main

{ [Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/routers/router.js'
In module tree:
    require-main

    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
]
  originalError: 
   { [Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/routers/router.js']
     errno: 34,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     path: '/Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/routers/router.js',
     syscall: 'open',
     fileName: '/Volumes/Users/dtdtdg/assets/js/src/routers/router.js',
     moduleTree: [ 'require-main' ] } }
```

Comment: seems like you have not installed almond.js as per your requirejs: > complie: > option: instruction

Answer (score 0):

My fault - I had assets/js/src/routers/router.js renamed.